# Simple Google script running strangely slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Sheets database setup I'm building, and some of the code is running extremely slowly (sometimes, not 100% of the time). This one in particular befuddles me:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rc = s.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rr = s.getActiveCell().getRow()
  var job = s.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue();
  if (rc == 2 && rr == 2 && s.getName()=='Entry' && job != "") {
    s.getRange("C1").setValue("LOADING...");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Helper");    
    var testVals = helperSheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
    var firstRow = testVals.filter(String).length+1;
    var workData = helperSheet.getRange("E3:J"+firstRow).getDisplayValues();
    s.getRange("C5:H").clearContent(); //tech to end time (work chart)
    s.getRange(5,3,firstRow-2,6).setValues(workData); //tech to end time (work chart)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    s.getRange("C1").clearContent();    
  }
}
```

After I cleaned it up a bit, I got it to complete in 2-3 seconds normally, but sometimes (and 100% of the time on my client's side), it times out at 30 seconds. Is there anything you can see that I've done wrong here that is slowing this down so much? I know it has a few too many function calls, but I've minimized those as much as I can. My only thought at this point is that the flush() calls are an issue. I use those so that "LOADING" appears as early as possible, and only clears once everything else is complete. Without them, it only appears for a half a second.

Any help would be wonderful as it may help guide me with the other scripts that are also running to slowly.

Also, after reading through various other answers here for other scripts that run/ran slowly, I've come across the idea of using installable triggers. Is there a reason that would make my script(s) run more quickly?

UPDATE:
I realized I could move the LOADING text add/delete calls to outside of the if test and thus remove the flush() calls. This way, editing another cell adds and removes the text simultaneously, so the user doesn't see it. And on my computer, it's running very quickly now. However, my client hasn't tested it yet. So, I think there's two questions now: 1) Does flush() really slow down a script that much? 2) Is there anything else silly going on in my code to make it slow...sometimes?

The new code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rc = s.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rr = s.getActiveCell().getRow()
  var job = s.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue();
  s.getRange("C1").setValue("LOADING...");
  if (rc == 2 && rr == 2 && s.getName()=='Entry' && job != "") {
    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Helper");    
    var testVals = helperSheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
    var firstRow = testVals.filter(String).length+1;
    var workData = helperSheet.getRange("E3:J"+firstRow).getDisplayValues();
    s.getRange("C5:H").clearContent(); //tech to end time (work chart)
    s.getRange(5,3,firstRow-2,6).setValues(workData); //tech to end time (work chart)
  }
    s.getRange("C1").clearContent();    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const job = sh.getRange(2, 2).getDisplayValue();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && sh.getName() == 'Entry' && job != "") {
    sh.getRange("C1").setValue("LOADING...");
    let hsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Helper");
    let workData = hsh.getRange("E3:J" + hsh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
    sh.getRange(5, 3, sh.getLastRow() - 4, 6).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(5, 3, workData.length, 6).setValues(workData);
  }
  sh.getRange("C1").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Cooper ! I just have a couple of questions. First, I couldn't use getLastRow for the helper sheet because it has a lot of different data in it for my various scripts. Will keeping the last row of column bit in the code slow it down, in your opinion? Second, I have to admit ignorance here, I have never used const or let in my script coding. Are they more efficient? I'll do my own research to understand them both, I'm just wondering if those different calls are better when having speed issues.

Comment: I think part of you problem is you use a lot of getValues()/setValues() in an onEdit(e).  Each of those is a server request, the data is not in memory.  So its a function of server response.

Comment: @TheWizEd - Thank you! I had expected this to be an issue, but I couldn't really figure out how to reduce the calls. I am wondering, 1) Do you know the answer to my second question above regarding this first answer? 2) Does it reduce the calls if I nest them? For a simple example, s.getRange("E2").setValue(hs.getRange("D2"); ? If this would help, there's a lot of nesting I could do to reduce multiple calls to single lines in a lot of my scripts for this sheet.